# Extract text between html tags parsed from xml

Tags: java, html, xml

Can anyone help me in extracting text from within the html tags to plain text?

I have parsed an xml and get some output as body which has html tags now i want to remove the tags and use the text.

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML Parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

For example
HTML is

```
<div style="height:240px;"><br>test: example<br>test1:example1</div>
```

You can get the html using

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element div = document.select("div[style=height:240px;]").first();
div.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [HTML Parser](http://www.google.com/#q=HTML+Parser+Java&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1&hl=en).

If the HTML is escaped, i.e. `&lt;` instead of `<` you might have to decode first.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirements you might try [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)

Take a look at [TextExtractor](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html) class:

`Using the default settings, the source segment:
"<div><b>O</b>ne</div><div title="Two"><b>Th</b><script>//a script </script>ree</div>"
produces the text "One Two Three"`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is remove HTML tags from a string, you can do this:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(?s)\\<.*?\\>", " ");
```